# A way to have a static backgound in an Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, background, rotation

Is there a way to have an Activity with a background which can't rotate, but where its children can rotate?

By exemple, I have a relativeLayout with an image background (l1), on this relative layout I have an other relative layout (l2) which contain TextViews, ...
If I'm in Landscape and then I switch in Portrait, I just want l2 rotate with the changement Landscape->Portrait.

Comment: Yes. You haven't provided nearly enough detail to provide more help though- what have you tried and where did you run into problems? Do you have any graphics that might explain your problem better?

Answer (score 1):

to rotate a view you can use rotate animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="600"       
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/>

</set>
```